# Hiding Sections of Admin

Tags: admin, configuration

I would like to hide sections of the magento admin for some users. I've seen [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723828/removing-an-item-from-magentos-admin-panel-navigation/769931#769931) for hiding things all together but am wondering if there is a way to conditionally hide sections of the admin for some users.

Comment: Do you need any advanced permissions management? Or just user / full admin section relation?

Comment: Just needed to hide most of the admin options for people who are just doing data entry while allowing the option to go in with the full admin for us when there was an issue on the site. Didn't realize the existing roles handles this pretty well already.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually baked into magento with roles.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-admin-users-roles

Setting the Role Resources in the second tab in setting up a role limits what options show up in the admin menu.